# Is there an equivalent to WinAPI GetColorDirectory in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, icc, color-profile

Is there an analogue of the function [`GetColorDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Or should I just call through a DLL?

The purpose is to get the path to the system directory with color profiles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you call it using the API:

```
[DllImport(DllImport.Mscms, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, BestFitMapping = false)]
internal static extern bool GetColorDirectory(IntPtr pMachineName, StringBuilder pBuffer, ref uint pdwSize);
```

Comment: I'd like to add that it is important to initialize pdwSize to something different from 0. As per the documentation, pdwSize indicates the size of the receiving buffer, in this case a StringBuilder. So I have: `uint pdwSize = 260; // MAX_PATH    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder((int)pdwSize);` before the call to `GetColorDirectory`. Afterwards, a simple `sb.ToString()` gives me the directory name (no need to truncate using the result in `pdwSize`).